# Linux kernel module to change the MTU size is not working

Tags: linux, network-programming, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, mtu

I am learning kernel modules and new to it.
I want to change the MTU size of the eth0. Here is the module program i have written.

The intention is to change the MTU size of eth0 to 1000.But its not getting changed. 
Can anyone tell me, what I am missing. If the approach itself is wrong , can you point me in the right direction?

```
#include <linux/module.h>       
#include <linux/kernel.h>       
#include <linux/init.h>         
#include <linux/etherdevice.h>
#include <linux/netdevice.h>

static int __init hello_2_init(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Hello, world 2\n");

        struct net_device dev;
        eth_change_mtu(&dev,1000); //calling eth_change_mtu
        return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_2_exit(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye, world 2\n");
}


int eth_change_mtu(struct net_device *dev, int new_mtu)
{
        dev->mtu = new_mtu;
        printk(KERN_INFO "New MTU is %d",new_mtu);
        return 0;
}

module_init(hello_2_init);
module_exit(hello_2_exit);
```

Comment: You don't need kernel module to do this, enter this command in terminal `ifconfig eth0 mtu 1000 up`

Answer (score 1):

You are setting MTU on structure that is not assigned with any actual network device. You declared **local** variable `dev` in init and then changed it's field.

You should first **find** network device you want to change. This is done with `__dev_get_by_name` like this:

```c
struct net_device *dev = __dev_get_by_name("eth0");
```

After that your changes will be applied to your network interface.